# How to integrate intercom chat to react-native mobile app?

Tags: react-native, intercom

I'm developing a mobile app which has a support feature for clients. Support is a chat session. We are planning to use intercom chat integration with our react-native mobile app. We are using React-Native. So is there any way to integrate intercom chat with my mobile app?

If it is possible, can i be able to change intercom chat UI with customized react-native components?

Any links helps would be appreciated?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can integrate Intercom in a react-native application. You can use 
 [react-native-intercom](https://github.com/tinycreative/react-native-intercom), this a wrapper of [Intercom-ios-sdk](https://developers.intercom.com/docs/ios-configuration) and does not have options to further customization (only launcher).

You'll have to write some native code hopefully everything is in the README.me

**About changing intercom UI:** *it is not possible*. Really, don't waste your time trying to do this. They simply don't offer this feature.

Their clients SDK are not open source even if they are in GitHub. If you go to [Intercom Android SDK](https://github.com/intercom/intercom-android) or [Intercom iOS SDK](https://github.com/intercom/intercom-ios) you would think that they open sourced them but if you see their files you're gonna see that it is just binary files. **You cannot edit them**. Or maybe you can but in a hacky way.

The only way to use your own components is to use their API directly and implement the UI from scratch. **I strongly recommend you to don't do it**. They have API call restrictions (500 requests per minute) which is easy to achieve because of the number of calls you'll have to send in order to make it work properly.